# How to reformat XML in IntelliJ but keep attributes on the same line

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

So the question is simple and has many similar ones asked here but yet they don't talk about this particular point.

I like the formatting feature but I hate that it does that:

```
<xs:element
   name="Foo"
   type="xs:string"/>
```

I would prefer it indents the tags but leaves the attributes alone and I can't find out how.

Result needed:

```
<xs:element name="Foo" type="xs:string"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Notable to say (maybe) that the file is not `.xml` but `.xsd`.

Answer (score 4):

Since .xsd is and XML itself you need to change the XML formatting settitngs.

In IDEA settings (**File** -> **Settings...** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) go to **Editor** -> **Code Style** -> **XML** and in **Wrap Attributes** dropdown choose **Do Not Wrap**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already tried that and all the options in the dropdown and nothing worked.